# elasticsearch: rename output fields of query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to rename the output fields from an elasticsearch query (like the "select .. AS .." in SQL)? I want to keep the original names of the fields in the index, and only modify their names in the result of the query.

I've read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/xyeUZ-jSzEo) but it says to re-index the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in Elasticsearch. If you need this kind of transformation, you'll need to do it application-side.

Comment: How about now, 2.5 years later? I see that ElasticSearch 6.1 has a Rename Processor. 

"_Renames an existing field. If the field doesn’t exist or the new name is already used, an exception will be thrown._" 

[Rename Process, ElasticSearch 6.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rename-processor.html)